# How can a user convert/migrate his own question?

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions

How can I convert/migrate my own question from one Stack Exchange site to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "migrate" it yourself.

If the question has no positively scored answers (or no answers at all) you can simply delete it (if you've registered your account) and post it again on the preferred site.

If it has answers that are upvoted, you will have to flag it using the custom reason and ask a moderator to migrate it for you. If there's a migration path between the site you're on and the one you would like it on, you can flag for migration there using the "flagging" --> "should be closed" --> "off topic" --> "belongs on another site" but this may not work if other users don't agree with the migration.